# SPSS string extraction

Tags: string, spss, text-extraction

I have a column with names of different persons separated by comma, for example, (all in 1 cell) Ben Lee, Paul Loy, Boy Lim. I want to separate each name into different columns. How will I do it? (in SPSS syntax).

Comment: currently experimenting with char.index and char.substr, no succes yet

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Variable-with-values-separated-by-commas-td5714349.html) with potential solution(s). Namely, credit David Marso and Jon Peck:

```
 * General Parser *. 
DATA LIST / X 1-80 (A). 
BEGIN DATA 11-0101-423-7384 
END DATA. 

VECTOR NUMS(10). 
COMPUTE #0=0. 
LOOP. 
COMPUTE #1=INDEX(X,'-'). 
COMPUTE #0=#0+1. 
IF #1>0 NUMS(#0)=NUMBER(SUBSTR(X,1,#1-1),F8). 
COMPUTE X=SUBSTR(X,#1+1). 
END LOOP IF #1=0. 
COMPUTE NUMS(#0)=NUMBER(X,F8). 
MATCH FILES FILE * / DROP X. 
LIST.
```

Or alternatively a python solution:

```
data list free /x(a13). 
begin data. 
1,13,5,6,99,8 
end data. 
dataset name data. 
begin program. 
def split(v): 
  return v.split(',') 
end program. 

spssinc trans result = v1 to v6 
/formula "split(x)".
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do repeat TXTname="Ben Lee" "Paul Loy" "Boy Lim"/VRname=BenLee PaulLoy BoyLim.
compute VRname=index(OriginalColumnName, TXTname)>0.
end repeat.
```

If there are many more names you might prefer to use standard variable names instead, and add the actual names in the labels instead:

```
do repeat TXTname="Ben Lee" "Paul Loy" "Boy Lim"/VRname=Name01 to Name03.
compute VRname=index(OriginalColumnName, TXTname)>0.
end repeat.
variable labels 
Name01 "Ben Lee"
Name02 "Paul Loy"
Name03 "Boy Lim".
```